# Spring Boot OAuth SSO with GitHub provides anonymous token - why?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, access-token

I’ve written an application based on the [Spring Guides article for using OAuth to provide SSO authentication](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).  I’ve successfully registered my application with GitHub and it is redirecting back to my callback URL after I log into GitHub with my credentials.  However the Spring Security Context for my application contains only an anonymous access token that I’m assuming has been provided by GitHub.  My question is why isn’t GitHub providing an access token with my full details?

YAML properties

```
client:
  clientId: <my client Id>
  clientSecret: <my client secret>
  accessTokenUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
  userAuthorizationUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
  clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  preEstablishedRedirectUri: <my custom redirect URI>
  useCurrentUri: false
```

[image: My OAuth application settings]

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying an oauth [scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps)?

> (no scope)    Grants read-only access to public information (includes
> public user profile info, public repository info, and gists)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  The problem was that the callback URL was different from the URL I was specifying in my YAML file for authenticating with GitHub (`/login/github`).  After I changed my callback URL to `localhost:8090/login/github` it worked fine.

I'm still not sure where `login/github` is established in the Spring Security code as an authentication API but that's another question.